# What's the way to communicate a set of Core Data objects stored in the background to the main thread?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, concurrency, delegation

Part of my iOS project polls a server for sets of objects, then converts and saves them to Core Data, to then update the UI with the results. The server tasks happens in a collection of NSOperation classes I call 'services' that operate in the background. If `NSManagedObject` and its `~Context` were thread safe, I would have had the services call delegate methods on the main thread like this one:

```
- (void)service:(NSOperation *)service retrievedObjects:(NSArray *)objects;
```

Of course [you can't pass around `NSManagedObject`s](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW7) like this, so this delegate method is doomed. As far as I can see there are two solutions to get to the objects from the main thread. But I like neither of them, so I was hoping the great StackOverflow community could help me come up with a third.

1. I could perform an `NSFetchRequest` on the main thread to pull in the newly added or modified objects. The problem is that the Core Data store contains many more of these objects, so I have to add quite some verbosity to communicate the right set of objects. One way would be to add a property to the object like `batchID`, which I could then pass back to the delegate so it would know what to fetch. But adding data to the store to fix my concurrency limitations feels wrong.
2. I could also collect the newly added objects' [`objectID`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/objectID) properties, put them in a list and send that list to the delegate method. The unfortunate thing though is that I have to populate the list *after* I save the context, which means I have to loop over the objects twice in the background before I have the correct list (first time is when parsing the server response). Then I still only have a list of `objectID`s, which I have to individually reel in with [`existingObjectWithID:error:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/existingObjectWithID%3aerror%3a) from the `NSManagedObjectContext` on the main thread. This just seems so cumbersome.

What piece of information am I missing? What's the third solution to bring a set of `NSManagedObject`s from a background thread to the main thread, without losing thread confinement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

epologee,

While you obviously have a solution you are happy with, let me suggest that you lose some valuable information, whether items are updated, deleted or inserted, with your mechanism. In my code, I just migrate the userInfo dictionary to the new MOC. Here is a general purpose routine to do so:

```
// Migrate a userInfo dictionary as defined by NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
// to the receiver context.
- (NSDictionary *) migrateUserInfo: (NSDictionary *) userInfo {

    NSMutableDictionary *ui = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity: userInfo.count];

    NSSet        *  sourceSet = nil;
    NSMutableSet *migratedSet = nil;

    for (NSString *key in [userInfo allKeys]) {

        sourceSet   = [userInfo valueForKey: key];
        migratedSet = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity: sourceSet.count];

        for (NSManagedObject *mo in sourceSet) {

            [migratedSet addObject: [self.moc objectWithID: mo.objectID]];
        }
        [ui setValue: migratedSet forKey: key];
    }
    return ui;

} // -migrateUserInfo:
```

The above routine assumes it is a method of a class which has an `@property NSManagedObjectContext *moc`.

I hope you find the above useful.

Andrew

Comment: I like that solution, thanks! You actually get the 'answered' flag for that, because it's more suited for the general purpose than mine is. Thanks @adonoho!

Answer (score 0):

There's a section of the Core Data Programming Guide that addresses [Concurrency with Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW4). In a nutshell, each thread should have its own managed object context and then [use notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW5) to synchronize the contexts.

Comment: Hi Caleb, thanks for taking the time. I am using the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` to pass it to `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` and getting the main thread context back in sync, but I shouldn't poke at the contents of that notification myself, should I? I'm stuck at retrieving the exact object set I got from the server into the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

After a little experimentation, I decided to go for a slight alteration to my proposed method number 2. While performing background changes on the context, keep a score of the objects you want to delegate back to the main thread, say in an `NSMutableArray *objectsOfInterest`. We eventually want to get to the `objectID` keys of all the objects in this array, but because the `objectID` value changes when you save a context, we first have to perform that `[context save:&error]`. Right after the save, use the `arrayFromObjectsAtKey:` method from the NSArray category below to generate a list of `objectID` instances, like so:

```
NSArray *objectIDs = [objectsOfInterest arrayFromObjectsAtKey:@"objectID"];
```

That array you can pass back safely to the main thread via the delegate (do make sure your main thread context is updated with `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification` by listening to the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`). When you're ready to reel in the objects of the background operation, use the `existingObjectsWithIDs:error:` method from the category below to turn the array of objectID's back into a list of working `NSManagedObject`s.

Any suggestions to improve the conciseness or performance of these methods is appreciated.

```
@implementation NSArray (Concurrency)

- (NSArray *)arrayFromObjectsAtKey:(NSString *)key {
   NSMutableArray *objectsAtKey = [NSMutableArray array];
   for (id value in self) {
       [objectsAtKey addObject:[value valueForKey:key]];
   }
   return objectsAtKey;
}

@end

@implementation NSManagedObjectContext (Concurrency)

- (NSArray *)existingObjectsWithIDs:(NSArray *)objectIDs error:(NSError **)error {
    NSMutableArray *entities = [NSMutableArray array];

    @try {
        for (NSManagedObjectID *objectID in objectIDs) {
            // existingObjectWithID might return nil if it can't find the objectID, but if you're not prepared for this,
            // don't use this method but write your own. 
            [entities addObject:[self existingObjectWithID:objectID error:error]];
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        return nil;
    }

    return entities;
}

@end
```